# Secure password-hashing in Java

Tags: java, security, cryptography, java-8

Here is an [article on password hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm), along with an [implementation](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#javasourcecode).

1. Is this code secure with number of iterations 10000, key length 256 and salt bytes 32?
2. Is there a rule-of-thumb for key length vs. salt bytes?
3. Regarding `key.destroy()` and `pbeKeySpec.clearPassword()`, is it necessary to "manually" destroy the key and clear the password? If so, does the order matter (e.g. should the key be destroyed before the password is cleared or vice-versa)?
4. Is it considered good practice to "zero out" password char array in the below example?
5. Are there vulnerabilities or incorrectly implemented sections in this code?

```
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;

/**
 * Request for code review on Stack Exchange:
 * https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56939/secure-password-hashing-in-java
 *
 * Some reference pages from around the web:
 * https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm
 * https://owasp.org/index.php/Hashing_Java
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267036/work-sun-misc-base64encoder-decoder-for-getting-byte
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860943/suggestions-for-library-to-hash-passwords-in-java
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464662/web-application-storing-a-password
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126061/pbekeyspec-what-do-the-iterationcount-and-keylength-parameters-influence
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption
 */
public abstract class PasswordDigester
{
    private static final int NUM_ITERATIONS = 10000;
    private static final int KEY_LENGTH = 256;
    private static final int SALT_BYTES = 32;

    /**
     * Hash a plain text password into the format iterations:salt:hashed-password.
     * @param newPassword A plain text password that needs to be hashed.
     * @return a hashed password in the format iterations:salt:hashed-password.
     */
    public static String getSaltedHash(String newPassword)
    {
        final byte[] nextRandomSalt = new byte[SALT_BYTES];
        try { SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG").nextBytes(nextRandomSalt); }
        catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { throw new IllegalStateException(e); }
        return getSaltedHash(NUM_ITERATIONS, nextRandomSalt, newPassword.toCharArray(), KEY_LENGTH);
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the number of iterations and the salt from a previously hashed password and use them to salt- and
     * hash a password candidate.  Useful to validate a password.
     * @param unhashedPasswordCandidate A password submitted by a client presumably to login to an application.
     * @param previouslyHashedPassword The password on record whose iterations and salt will be used to hash
     *                                 the unhashed password candidate.
     * @return a hashed password that can be validated for correctness against the previously hashed password.
     */
    public static String getSaltedHash(String unhashedPasswordCandidate, String previouslyHashedPassword)
    {
        String[] params = previouslyHashedPassword.split(":");
        int iterations = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
        byte[] randomizedSalt = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(params[1]);
        return getSaltedHash(iterations, randomizedSalt, unhashedPasswordCandidate.toCharArray(), KEY_LENGTH);
    }

    private static String getSaltedHash(int iterations, byte[] randomizedSalt, char[] password, int keyLength)
    {
        try
        {
            PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password, randomizedSalt, iterations, keyLength);
            SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            SecretKey key = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
            String result =
                iterations +
                ":" +
                DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(randomizedSalt) +
                ":" +
                DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(key.getEncoded());

            //  Note: key.destroy() always throws DestroyFailedException, so I've commented it out.
            //key.destroy();
            pbeKeySpec.clearPassword();

            //  For security, "zero out" password char array.
            for(int i = 0; i < password.length; i++) { password[i] = '0'; }

            return result;
        }
        catch(InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

With the above settings this is generated (new lines after each colon):

> 10000:
>
> pwYOF5KPSB+hbLVmuBxuVG0H12GReS+8A+UgSiWrpbM=:
>
> 63M+swkV4binnRKXQYgZJbJJtzT9asR0w0bJgytJZpg=

Any advice or words of caution or ways to secure or correct this code would be welcome.

Answer (score 7):

Okay, be warned, I know a little Java syntax, but I am really unfamiliar with the objects of Java. So if I get something incorrect, I'd appreciate a friendly reminder!

I'll see what I can point out...

So at first I notice you're supplying a static number of iterations. The number of iterations *should* vary depending on the computer that's encrypting. There's a good Q&A on Sec.SE that explains [how you should determine the number of iterations](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3959/recommended-of-iterations-when-using-pkbdf2-sha256) you should use. Basically though, it boils down to as many as your machine can do without affecting performance dramatically. After you determine how many iterations suits you best, *that* number should be the static number.

This next one I had to do a little research for, but let's quickly note this line:

```
SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")
```

Here's an article (a bit old, but I believe relevant) which gives some background on this method. [The author proposes that it's best to include the provider](http://www.cigital.com/justice-league-blog/2009/08/14/proper-use-of-javas-securerandom/) to prevent different PRNGs on different installations.

As said at the beginning, I'm not familiar with this area of Java, but *it looks* like [you're doing what's desired](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac), which would be encrypt then MAC. If I read your code wrong, let me know!

In regards to your third question, I think it would make more sense to `destroy` and then `clear`.

In regards to your fourth, I can't see a benefit or a downside. However, I'm not very familiar with Java vulnerabilities! So there may be some sort of leakage I'm not aware of, which could compromise the security of `PBEKeySpec`'s password. But you clear the password with `clearPassword()`. My best guess would be that it's not completely necessary!

---

Other than that, the largest flaw I can see is the lack of formatting.

What I mean by this are things such as the two-lined `try/catch`:

```
try { SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG").nextBytes(nextRandomSalt); }
catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { throw new IllegalStateException(e); }
```

Compressing this into these two lines only made it harder to read. I suggest you give the code some space to breathe!

It's Java convention to have the first brace on the same line as the statement. So your two lines of

```
try
{
```

really should just be one. But that's just nit-picking!

I don't see a reason not to have the last `for` loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
    password[i] = '0'; 
}
```

Also note that I added a space between the `for` and `(`.

The opening brace after the last `catch` should be on the same line as the `catch`!

Comment: The number of iterations should be chosen to be the maximum tolerable value. However, it still needs to be constant for the hashing scheme to make any sense.

Comment: That's what I intended @200_success. I'll see about making an edit to clarify!